# Facing issues while capturing screenshot from tfs board - Windows Application c#

Tags: c#, screenshot

Trying to capture screenshot from tfs online board. In order to achieve it used the web browser object of windows form. Used below code for same:
InitializeComponent();

```
        imagePath = imageName;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        TempImage = tempImage;
        string altusername = "***";
        string altpassword = "***";            
        string auth = altusername + ":" + altpassword;
        auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(auth));
        string header = "Authorization: Basic " + auth;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url, null, null, header);

        timer1.Interval = (1000) * (60);             
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
```

Initially it used to work perfectly fine. But now since past few days a pop is shown asking for the credentials as [image]shown in attached screenshot. When we click on "OK", then only it moves forward. Is there anything that got changed in Microsoft dlls and what is the solution for the same ?

Comment: As you mentioned that it worked before, you can try to check if it works on another client machine. Also try to modify the security settings in Internet Explorer, follow these steps:
Start Internet Explorer. Click Tools  >> Internet Options  >>  Security tab >>  Internet  >>  Custom Level  >> In the Security Settings dialog box, make sure that "Automatic logon with current username and password" is enabled under User Authentication  >> Click OK.

Comment: We have verified that now it does not work in any of the client machine. Can it be the case that something changed from Microsoft

Comment: It's not related TFS (on-premise ). You can try if this works in local  TFS (on-premise).